# How do you add tags with Gatling?

Tags: gatling

I have just installed Gatling and am trying to run the quick start scenario. However, I do not see anywhere in the recorder a place to add tags. In fact, the word "tag" appears nowhere on the recorder panel. I must be missing something really obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Option to add tags is available after clicking "Start" - during scenario recording.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that my vagrant instance was interfering on the port causing the recorder to come up, but never get to the second screen where you can enter tags.